# What is the most ideal way of implementing an instant and interactive preview of a web app in a Nuxtjs app?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, content-management-system, preview

I'm working on two webapps built with **Nuxtjs** which are like e-learning apps. One app (**App1**) acts as a CMS from which a teacher prepares courses, and in and the other app (**App2**) is like an end result where a student can go through the content created.

Now I want to implement an instant preview of the **App2** in the **App1** when content is being built.

So I was wondering what the best approach, that's quick and seamless, is to go about it?

- I was thinking of sharing the components in an NPM package between the two apps but the thing is that almost all the pages of the **App2** should be used in the **App1**.
- Or loading the **App2** in an Iframe in the App 1 but no sure how to instantly show the changes being made in **App1**?

All ideas given is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I guess you want to create two apps that have common components, and different logic, sharing components via npm package is a really good idea, I think you can also use [Layout](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/components-glossary/layout/) feature, you can have more than 2 scenes, But that can make the app little bit complex, it depends on how to organize your business logic.